Quarkus loading environment variables without applying escape rules
To connect to the database with Quarkus (and Hibernate) I use the following configuration in the application.properties file for the password.
quarkus.datasource.password = ${PW}

As my pod runs in a k8s cluster that has been created via Terraform I get the password randomly generated and provided as kubernetes secret.
Let's assume I got a password like pa$$word.
No matter if I use the PW as environmental variable or QUARKUS_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD, the password that is used to connect to the database via jdbc always ends up in pa$word as th $$ is considered to be escaped.
To achieve the correct password I would need to provide pa$$$$word as environment variable which I cannot do as it is being created automatically and therefore no escaping is done on infrastructure code.
Is there a possibility to tell Quarkus to load environment variables/secrets as they are?

don't you have a way to say use this characters? if not, have you tried encoding base64 and then create the secret?

Actually, yes, my current workaround is to limit the characters which are allowed for generating a password. But it feels for me that it only masks the problem. If you might use the software later in another context you might face the issue again.

I would say, file an issue on https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues
